# wget has a 4 second delay

Tags: command-line, wget

I have tried to `wget` a page with windows/mac, and the response is instant 
while the the Linux application delays for 4 seconds before it shows the response.

The command I ran is:

```
wget http://192.168.0.135/test.cgi?cmd= -O test.txt
```

The result in Ubuntu:

```
--2011-03-04 14:21:17--  http://192.168.0.135/test.cgi?cmd=
Connecting to 192.168.0.135:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `test.txt'

[ <=>                                   ] 17          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2011-03-04 14:21:22 (1.88 MB/s) - `test.txt' saved [17]
```

Running the command in Mac yields:

```
--2011-03-04 14:22:33--  http://192.168.0.135/test.cgi?cmd=
Connecting to 192.168.0.135:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `test.txt'

[ <=>                                   ] 17          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2011-03-04 14:22:33 (755 KB/s) - `test.txt' saved [17]
```

I believe it may related to some setting in the network configuration, such as packet size, window frame, but I have no idea how to set this.

The output of `uname -a` (kernel version):

> Linux linux017 2.6.35-25-generic-pae #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 19:01:46 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

The version of wget (`wget --version`) is: `GNU Wget 1.12`

Comment: Can you provide the link you are trying?

Comment: As a point of reference I don't experience any delay with wget on Ubuntu 10.10 retrieving from an Apache server with Comcast cable.

Comment: Can you output the version part (e.g. `1.12`) from `wget --version` on your systems?

Comment: Possibly a DNS issue. Is your configuration for DNS the same on Mac and Ubuntu?

Comment: @Lekensteyn:Did this originally have a domain name instead of an IP?  If he's actually using IP addresses, it's definitely not a DNS issue.

Comment: @Azendale: I did not suggest about DNS, @Reuben Swartz did. @guisius: what does `ping 192.168.0.135` say on both machines? Usually, the first ping is slow due to routing decisions and the next ones should be almost equal.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux in general and Ubuntu in particular, I often have to wait for an IPv6 DNS query to time out before it will look for IPv4 addresses.

Comment: If he's using an actual IP address, 192.168.0.135, there is no DNS lookup involved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it with IP address instead of domain name. 
If it's instant - then your local DNS server might be overloaded (while windows cache it).
You may try GOogle's one(8.8.8.8), or install pdnsd - local DNS cache.